# JQuery DataTables does not recognize data loaded

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, datatables

For some reason, my JQuery DataTable is adding data to the table, but it still says "0 to 0 of 0 entries. Trying to use the search box does not actually search through my data, and sorting by my one column does not change the order. I don't get any errors in firebug, so I don't really know where to go from here. Thank you for looking.

Here is the javascript:

```
var oTable = $("#tblAddUsers").dataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "bSearching": true,
            "bSort": true,
            "bFilter": true,
            sAjaxSource: '@Url.Action("GetUserList", "ClassSchedule")',
            aoColumns: [
                {
                    bVisible: false
                },
                {
                    sWidth: "250px",
                    bSortable: true

                },
                {
                    mRender: function () { return '<button class="clAddUser">Add</button>'; },
                    sWidth: "200px"
                }
            ],

            fnRowCallback: function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {

                $('button', nRow).on('click', function () { 
                    test(aData[0]);
                });
            }


        });
```

My Controller code:

```
public JsonResult GetUserList()
    {
        var addUserList = (from u in db.t_user
                           join m in db.t_user_membership on u.user_id equals m.user_id
                           where m.membership_date > DateTime.Today
                           select new { user_id = u.user_id, full_name = u.first_name + " " + u.last_name }).ToList();

        return Json(new { aaData = addUserList.Select(x => new string [] { x.user_id.ToString(), x.full_name }) }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

My GET response looks like this:

```
{"aaData":[["2","test Spouse"],["3","David Parker"]]}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="AddUserPopup" style="display:none" title="">
<span>Add Users</span>
<div style="width: 500px; height: 300px;" id="dialog">
        <table id="tblAddUsers">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>User Name</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            </tbody>
        </table>

</div>
```

Here is a screenshot of what I get:

[image]

Comment: where's your code for the search?

Comment: @jonmrich Ok, I've added the controller code as well. Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a server-side datasource, you need to handle the searching, sorting & paging in the server code.

Have a look at the parameters that get passed to & from the server [here](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/server-side).  You're not passing any of this information - for example you get `Showing 0 of 0 entries` because you're not returning `iTotalRecords` and `iTotalDisplayRecords` in the json data. The returned object should look something like this:

```
return Json(new
{
    param.sEcho,
     iTotalRecords = rowCount,
     iTotalDisplayRecords = rowCount,
    aaData = result,
 }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
```

If you look at Firebug's Net panel, you can see all the parameters that are sent in the request when loading the datatable. You need to get these in your server code and use them in your query, e.g `sSearch` for searching, `iDisplayStart` and `iDisplayLength` for paging.

I'd do something like this:

```
public JsonResult GetUserList(jQueryDataTableParamModel p)
{
    var addUserList = from u in db.t_user
       join m in db.t_user_membership on u.user_id equals m.user_id
       where m.membership_date > DateTime.Today
       select new mymodel
       { 
           user_id = u.user_id, 
           full_name = u.first_name + " " + u.last_name 
       };
//paging
    var displayedItems = addUserList.Skip(p.iDisplayStart).Take(p.iDisplayLength);
    var rowCount = addUserList.Count();

//  project into json for datatable
    var result = from d in displayedItems
                         select new object[]
                         {
                            d.user_id,
                            d.full_name
                          };
    return Json(new
    {
        param.sEcho,
        iTotalRecords = rowCount,
        iTotalDisplayRecords = rowCount,
        aaData = result,
     }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The `jQueryDataTableParamModel` parameter comes from a good tutorial on using server-side datatables in MVC [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155422/jQuery-DataTables-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Integration-Part)

Comment: OP doesn't use server-side processing according to the initialization options, so your post doesn't really answer the question why `Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries` text is shown.

Comment: Thanks @markpsmith for the example. This may not be what I was doing originally but this is exactly what I needed to do for what I was trying to accomplish. I have the correct records and the search is working like its supposed to. Thanks for your help.